# How to set display width for Blazor server app?

Tags: blazor

By default the app uses Bootstrap. I've tried using several div classes in the MainLayout.razor but the app fills the entire screen width. How can I set it to, for instance, 75% of screen width, when the app is running on a desktop (or laptop)?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `site.css` file to set `max-width` on the `app` container. You can also set `margin: 0 auto;` if you want the [content centered](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/#auto-and-centering).

```css
app {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Add these */
    max-width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `div` around the `sidebar` and `main` `div`s, but you'll need to set it as `d-flex`.

```html
<div class="d-flex w-75">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>

    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```